# Attach image to Twitter Status from Direct Message media

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi guys i trying to post a status using Twitter `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json` POST request API.
I also want to update the status with attached image, but the image is already on direct message, so i get a direct message by using GET request and i get the message's object like this..

```js
{
  type: 'message_create',
  id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  created_timestamp: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  message_create: {
    target: { recipient_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    sender_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    message_data: {
      text: 'This is trigger message with image,oy! https://x.xx/xxxxxxxxx',
      entities: [Object],
      attachment: {
        type: 'media',
        media: {
          id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
          id_str: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          indices: [ 39, 62 ],
          media_url: 'https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/data/dm/xxxxx/xxxxx/gr_SQawQ.jpg',
          media_url_https: 'https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/data/dm/xxxxx/xxxxx/gr_SQawQ.jpg',
          url: 'https://x.xx/xxxxx',
          display_url: 'pic.twitter.com/xxxxx',
          expanded_url: 'https://twitter.com/messages/media/xxxxxx',
          type: 'photo',
          sizes: {
            medium: [Object],
            thumb: [Object],
            large: [Object],
            small: [Object]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how you **post a status with an attached image** from direct message's media image like above??

I have try using the `attachment.media.id` and `attachment.media.id_str` from that response as a value for `media_ids` param like this, but still get an error `Invalid media.`

```js
const text = message.message_create.message_data.text;
const attachment = message.message_create.message_data.attachment;

const payload = {
    status: text
};
attachment && (payload.media_ids = [attachment.media.id_str]); //i've tried using id_str and id

T.post('statuses/update', payload, (error, data, response) => {
    if (!error) {
        resolve({
            message: `successfuly posting new status with DM id: ${message.id}`,
            data
        });
    } else {
        reject(error);
    };
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-post the media from a Direct Message via the same `media_id_string`, as it has already been "used". You also cannot post the URL and have the image display, as it is private to the the sender and receiver.

You will need to implement a three-stage process:

- download the image from the Direct Message to a local file. You will [need to use OAuth user authentication](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/message-attachments/guides/retrieving-media) to do this.
- [upload the media](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/overview) as a new entity on Twitter, and grab the new `media_id_string`
- post a [new Tweet](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update), with the `media_id_string` attached.

Note that you should think about the privacy implications of reposting images sent via Direct Message, and be sure that the sender is aware that they may be reposted as publically-accessible.

Comment: yes, the sender also have been told before, that the dm will be resposted as publically-accessible